# Grails: HTTPS and blocked content

Tags: grails, https

I have a grails app the is running on Tomcat and we are using SSL.  The problem is that some of our javascript files that are being included via application resources are being blocked as insecure content:

[blocked] The page at https://mysite.com/supplementalInformation/edit?rquid=E24CF6C9-4DEF-48D3-B83C-DC4404F9DC78 ran insecure content from http://mysite.com/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js.

How do I get this to not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources plugin generates absolute links. Try to set serverUrl="https://mysite.com/" in config.groovy. This will fix your problem.
Or better take a look [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html). The intresting param for you is **linkOverride**. Define it with https protocol for your static resources.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `<g:javascript library="jquery"/>` declared in layout/gsp where you have used jquery?

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with https sites, you must use all sites https to prevent blocking

If need jquery use:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<g:javascript library='jquery' />
```

Hope this helps